# WPF dashed Rectangle shape does not render correctly

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is my XAML code (I have no code-behind):

```
<Canvas>
    <Line 
        X1="100" Y1="100"
        X2="200" Y2="100"
        Stroke="Black"
        StrokeDashArray="1 1"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        />
    <Rectangle Height="20" 
               Canvas.Left="101" 
               Canvas.Top="141" 
               Width="50" 
               Stroke="Black"
               StrokeThickness="1"
               StrokeDashArray="1 1"
               StrokeEndLineCap="Flat"
               StrokeDashOffset="1"
               SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               />
</Canvas>
```

During design time, the Designer Window shows the following (which is correct):

[image]

But when I run the application, it gets rendered as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the line is fine but the rectangle is drawn as solid, although it should have a dashed stroke.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?  I am on Windows 10 Pro, my screen resolution is 2560 x 1440, with a DPI setting of 96, and an effective DPI of 93.03.  I am using the latest Expression Blend version as well as the latest Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

**EDIT:**

The problem is fixed, see [Richardissimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5198140/richardissimo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51407898/360840) below.  Final render:

[image]

Comment: Remove StrokeDashOffset

Comment: @Flot2011 I removed it but it didn't help.

Comment: Try `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on the Canvas or the top-level element.

Comment: @Clemens `UseLayoutRounding="True"` on the `Canvas`, or anywhere up the visual tree didn't fix it for me; it made the horizontal line slightly broader; but no obvious effect on the rectangle.

Comment: @Clemens I tried it and there's no change in the output.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it. However, my screen resolution is higher.

Comment: Just to make sure there isn't any default Style magic, also set `StrokeDashCap="Flat"`.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your efforts.  When I was posting it, I was hoping the question would get your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fascinating. Answer is at the bottom...

I decided to set up a resource shared by both to be sure nothing funny was going on, and to help work through the various combinations I'm about to describe.

```
    <DoubleCollection x:Key="strokeDashArray">
        <system:Double>1</system:Double>
        <system:Double>1</system:Double>
    </DoubleCollection>
```

where

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

and then used that on both the line and rectangle by changing them to use

```
    StrokeDashArray="{StaticResource strokeDashArray}"
```

The images in the question show the rectangle is grey but the line (in pixels) becomes "black white" (repeating).

What I found interesting was to change the values to "1 2": the line (in pixels) becomes "black white white" (repeating) but the rectangle becomes "black black white" (repeating).

Changing it to "2 1" makes the line "black black white"; but the rectangle becomes "black grey grey".

Changing it to "2 2" makes the line "black black white white" but the rectangle "black grey white grey".

So the Rectangle is definitely rendering it differently than the Line.

I thought it might be the fact that one was at X=100 and one at X=101, so the anti-aliasing might be offset; but changing 101 to 100 made no difference, and moving the rectangle so the top or bottom lines were aligned with the line also didn't help.

Neither did changing the `StrokeDashOffset` to 0.

Interestingly, changing the `StrokeThickness` of the rectangle to 1.1 made it a bit more "dotty"; but not consistently, so that's not a solution.

Got it: add this to the Rectangle:

```
RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
```

Comment: Amazing, yes, this fixes it.  THANK YOU, I really am speechless.  One question: How did you come up with the `RenderOptions` setting?  Have you used it before elsewhere?  Again, thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu. No, never seen this problem before, but you can see my research, and that I had got the idea that it was rendering with antialiasing. A bit more searching based on that and I found the answer.

Comment: The thing is, I have always thought of anti-aliasing as being preferred, and here, just the opposite is true.